# Send xml file as payload in cypress post request

Tags: cypress

How to send xml file as payload in cypress post request:
When i am trying to send xml file/txt file as post request payload, am not able to do ad getting bad request

Comment: Can you please add a code example that you've tried? And any specific error messages?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... (pardon the formatting)

```
it('Post File to URL', () => {
    const yourFile = 'C:\\PathToYourFile\\YourFile.xml'
    cy
        .readFile(yourFile)
        .then(function (text) {
           cy.log(text)
           postXML(text)
        }
)})

function postXML(text) {
    return cy.request({
        url: 'https://yourURL.com',
        method: 'POST',
        body: text,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'content-length': '1000',
            'connection': 'close',
            'soapAction': ''
        }
})}
```